# Start point for sticky submenu

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have three menus on a new build.

Menu 1 a sticky menu using `position: fixed; min-height: 30px;`

Menu 2 scrolls with `position: relative;`

Menu 3 (half way down the page) starts with `position: absolute;` then as the user scrolls changes to `position: fixed;`

Menu 1 and 3 need to stack on scroll and currently they are overlapping.

The site is built with WP and been messing with this Javascript to control the start position of Menu 3 but it's not being applied. Code has been added to theme functions.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enfold_customization_custom_scripts' );
function enfold_customization_custom_scripts() {
?>
<script type = "text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var menu = document.querySelector('#sub_menu1')
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect().top;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= menuPosition) {
        menu.style.position = 'fixed';
        menu.style.top = '40px';
    } else {
        menu.style.position = 'static';
        menu.style.top = '';
    }
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Above code is used from this source: [Codepen: position: sticky with Simply JS](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/piFxy)

What I'm trying to achieve is the Menu 3 scrolling to the correct position below Menu 1 and sticking. When the user scrolls up and down the menu needs to stick and unstick at the correct point on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix:

```
 <script>
(function($){
        var calc_scroll = function() {
            var header = $('#header').height(),
                scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                if(scroll >= 450) {
                    $('#sub_menu1').css('padding-top', '30px');
                } else {
                    $('#sub_menu1').css('padding-top', '0px');
                }
        }

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            calc_scroll();
        });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```